# When to use worth vs worth while?

Tags: verbs, nouns

I was going through this link - http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/worth-or-worthwhile

However, I cannot find that the following sentence is wrong.

I wrote -

In conclusion, it all depends on the student whether taking a gap year is worth or not.

My teacher corrected -

In conclusion, it all depends on the student whether taking a gap year is **worthwhile** or not.

My question is why it is worthwhile and not worth. 
Here the gap year is like a noun. So, I am saying whether that noun is worth or not. 
For example - 
Do you think that buying a car (noun) is worth or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The adjective *worth* requires a complement: something which has worth must be *worth **something***:

> This book is worth **$25**.
>   This book is worth **reading**.
>   Reading this book is worth **my time**.

So "taking a gap year is worth" is ungrammatical, because there is no complement.

*Worthwhile* is formally an adjective, but it has the sense of *worth* plus the complement *while*, in the sense *time*.

> Taking a gap year is worthwhile = Taking a gap year is worth the student's time.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of "worth", you need the idiom [*worth it*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/worth+it):

> 1)  it is useful or important
>   2)  it is rewarding despite the difficulties involved

Then you could use *worth it* or *worthwhile*:

> In conclusion, it all depends on the student whether taking a gap year is **worth it** or not.
>   In conclusion, it all depends on the student whether taking a gap year is **worthwhile** or not.

The meaning of these is the same.